# Override $exceptionHandler behaviour in service unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, angularjs-service

I have a service which throws an error, and I'd like to unit test that, but somehow I cannot get it overwritten, which I did manage to do for controllers:

```
describe('some test', function () {
var myService, exceptionHandler;


beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myModule', function($exceptionHandlerProvider) {

    $exceptionHandlerProvider.mode("log");


}));

beforeEach(inject(function ($injector, $exceptionHandler) {
    exceptionHandler = $exceptionHandler;
    myService = $injector.get('myService');
}));



it('should throw an error', function () {
    theService.somefunction('create an error');
    expect(exceptionHandler.errors.length).toBe(1);
    expect(exceptionHandler.errors[0].message).toBe('some text');
    });

});
});
```

in somefunction I just do this:

```
throw new Error('some text')
```

The problem is that the error is just logged to the console in Karma, so it seems to be rethrown rather then logged.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's advised to use sinon when stubbing an object (will show both ways though):

```js
describe('some test', function () {
  var myService, exceptionHandler = {};

  exceptionHandler.fn = function(exception, cause) {
    throw exception;
  };

  beforeEach(module('myModule', function($provide) {

    $provide.factory('$exceptionHandler', function(){
      return function(exception, cause){
        return exceptionHandler.fn(exception, cause);
      };
    });

  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    myService = $injector.get('myService');
  }));

  it('should throw an error', function () {
      var old = exceptionHandler.fn, caught = false, message = '';
    
      exceptionHandler.fn = function(exception, cause) {
         caught = true;
         message = exception.message;
      };
      myService.somefunction('create an error');
      expect(caught).toBe(true);
      expect(message).toBe('message');
      exceptionHandler.fn = old; //restore
      
      // using sinon.js
      sinon.stub(exceptionHandler, 'fn', function(exception){ });
      myService.somefunction('create an error');
      expect(exceptionHandler.fn.called).toBe(true);
      expect(exceptionHandler.fn.getCall(0).args[0]).toMatch(/message/);
      exceptionHandler.fn.restore();
  });
});
```

sinon makes it easier to stub stuff, and check the call count and restore functionality after you're done